# how to stop ng-repeat from reordering the items in an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, predicate

I have an array of objects over which i am iterating using `ng-repeat` .

here is my model

```
var myArray =[{$$hashKey: "object:2",name:"A"},{$$hashKey: "object:1",name:"B"}]
```

Here is my html markup. I also have an `orderby` as given below for which the `predicate` is empty string `""`

```
<div ng-repeat="ob in myArray | orderBy:predicate:reverse">{{ob.name}}</div>
```

And i expect it to display the names in the order `A,B`.

But it is actually rendering the dom in the order of `hashkey` as `B,A`.How can i avoid this?

Comment: do add `id` to field `myArray` which would be unique field & then apply `orderBy` filter over that `id`(unique) attribute

Comment: <div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' ">
    {{model.name}}
</div>  id or Propety

Comment: @PankajParkar i cannot modify the array as it is been sent in that form from the backend

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/NQqmUkoOOX3k6pF0KTFu?p=preview. Come up with a plunkr reproducing the problem. Why are you explicitely setting the $$hashKey of objects. Those are internal details that angular should do by itself.

Comment: @JBNizet yes these are internal details ,i added it manually to give an idea

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat orders by index. always. you are doing something else wrong here ;)
if i use your code it displays A,B as expected.
unless you are using some utterly old angular version (which one are you using?) you are doing something wrong somewhere else. please post some more code then.

Comment: Angular 1.3.16 is been used and i will try to reproduce with the same object

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem.

It is not displaying in the order of hashkey. It is just dumping the data in the same sequence it is receiving it.

Your problem is `predicate` There is no property named predicate in your object. So your condition `"ob in myArray | orderBy:predicate:reverse"` is not ordering on name.

In order to order by name, you have to use

```
"ob in myArray | orderBy:'name'"
```